# How can I mock new call creation in junit?

Tags: java, junit

Could someone help me to mock the new object creation and to call the class method:

```
public String login(){
    new SampleClass3().method(sam);//need to mock this line
    return "welcome to login page";
}
```

Comment: You can't.  Redesign your code to accept a `Supplier<SampleClass3>` or the like, or have it passed in.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Redesign is the better approach; but technically, one can use PowerMock in order to mock calls to *new*.

Comment: Thank you very much sir; just showed my gratitude ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a mocking framework such as PowerMock. You can find an explanation how to do that [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockconstructor) for example.

So, although the comment by Louis is technically incorrect he is perfectly right about the fact that you **better not** do that.

First of all, using Powermock *can* lead to all kind of subtle or not so subtle issues. I spent many hours "fixing" broken unit tests - to figure in the end that there was another weird Powermock thing going on; and no problem whatsoever in our production code.

Then: the real thing is - you created hard to test code: as *creating* other objects is something better not happens like this. Instead, you should be looking into ways to do **dependency injection**. Either by passing a SampleClass3 object via constructor; or by passing a factory for that class, or by using an injection framework.

Long story short: you want to learn how to create testable code, by watching these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) for example. That time is a better investment than to learn about PowerMock; believe me.